# Return rows in pandas based on values in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

Needed some help with pandas...I'm working on [this data](http://data.un.org/Data.aspx?d=EDATA&f=cmID:ES&c=2,5,6,7,8&s=_crEngNameOrderBy:asc,_enID:asc,yr:desc&v=1) and I'm trying to calculate some changes over time per region. 
Basically, I'm trying to find the oldest quantity and the newest quantity for each area in question. I have code that can give me the year of the most recent and oldest data recordes, however I need to gather the whole row so I can work on the 'quantity' column. Any inputs? here is what i have :

`df.groupby(['Country or Area'])['Year'].max()`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get oldest and newest with `idxmin` and `idxmax`

`df.loc[df.groupby(['Country or Area'])['Year'].idxmin()]`

Answer (score 1):

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['Country or Area','Year'])
df.groupby('Country or Area').agg(['first','last']).stack()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use idxmin() and idxmax().  Something like:

```
grp = df.groupby(['Country or Area'])

for name,group in grp:
    print(name)

    minidx = group['Year'].idxmin()
    maxidx = group['Year'].idxmax()

    print(f"min: {group['Year'][minidx]} {group['Quantity'][minidx]}")
    print(f"max: {group['Year'][maxidx]} {group['Quantity'][maxidx]}")
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 
[agg functions of *groupby()*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.1/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html)

You can pass the functions or a dict of functions to the columns you need to aggregate

In your case the code should be like [Crish solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60235366/11843382) is the better way to do it.

Sort the dataframe by the value to check and then group and get by *.agg()* the result that you need

The *[stack()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)*  method works to deflate the df level